# allow multiple window.open() of the same link to an mvc action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an action that does something which takes a long time to process.

I have a link to that action and when the user clicked that link, I would like to open the action in a new window. I would pass a parameter to that action which it would process.

However, when the new window pops up and the user clicked again the link, no new window pops up.

I want a new window foreach time the user click the link.

```
var generatedGuid = GenerateGuid();
window.open("url/mvcAction?guid="+generatedGuid,"_blank","width=400, height=400");
```

Comment: your code is working as you want I think you have some other issue which is not addressed as a code piece .

Answer (score 0):

Added window name `MyWindow`

```
MyWindow = window.open("url/mvcAction?guid="+generatedGuid,"MyWindow","width=400, height=400");

MyWindow.focus();
```